# When does a group act effectively and holomorphically on some Riemann surface?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, lie-groups, riemann-surfaces

Given a Riemann surface $X$, we have some fairly standard methods for identifying which groups $G$ admit an effective and holomorphic action $G \times X \to X$. For instance, some fairly elementary arguments show that the only finite groups acting effectively and holomorphically on $\mathbb{P}^1$ are finite cyclic groups, $D_4, A_4, S_4$, and $A_5$. (See e.g. Miranda, Ch. III p. 80 for these arguments.) Another result is Hurwitz' theorem, which says that given a Riemann surface $X$, the only such finite groups must have order $\leq 84(g(X) - 1)$.

Now let's instead fix a group $G$. (Maybe you want $G$ to be a Lie group, maybe finite.) **What results tell us about the (non)existence of a Riemann surface $X$ on which $G$ acts effectively and holomorphically?** I'd be surprised to hear that given $G$, we can always construct such an $X$.

Unlike the problem of finding groups given $X$, I have not heard anything about this kind of problem while learning about Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Presumably you want a connected Riemann surface?

Comment: I like this question a lot. Your question also motivates if given a group Theres some kind of structure on the set of Riemann Surfaces which the group acts effectively and holomorphically upon.

Comment: Every countable group acts effectively and holomorphically (and freely, properly discontinuously) on some Riemann surface. This is an elementary exercise in the theory of covering spaces. Of course, if you also consider actions of Lie groups of positive dimension, your options are very limited.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I understand when you drop reference to complex structure, but I'd need to convince myself the argument still works when you do not. But I guess that just amounts to checking an explicit construction. And there aren't many to check.

Comment: It is the same construction, just lift the complex structure to the covering space to make it group-invariant.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Sorry -- I did not even think the base would be a Riemann surface, which is must be why I'm getting confused. I thought that given $G$, we would form a surface with $\pi_1 = G$ and take its universal cover. But that base cannot be a Riemann surface for general $G$, because don't Riemann surfaces have restrictions on their $\pi_1$?

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to write an answer then. The thing is that every countable group is a quotient of a free group of countably infinite rank. The latter is obviously the fundamental group of a Riemann surface (complex plane minus the set of integers).

Comment: @MoisheKohan Oh, what I said is only the case in the compact case. Then I understand.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In fact:

> Theorem: Any finite group $G$ is the automorphism group of a compact Riemann surface, and more generally a smooth projective algebraic curve over any algebraically closed field.

The Riemann surface case is  proved by L. Greenberg, *Maximal groups and signatures*, Ann. Math, Studies 1973, and second by M. Madan and M. Rosen, *The automorphism group of a function field*. Proc. Amer. Math. Soc(1992)

Answer (score 20):

Donu's answer is correct but amounts to killing a fly with a gun shot: Greenberg proves a harder result than the one needed for the problem.

Theorem. Let $G$ be a countable group. Then there exists a Riemann surface $X$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $Aut(X)$ acting properly discontinuously and freely on $X$.

Proof. Since $G$ is countable, it has (at most) countably many generators. Let $F_\infty$ denote the free group of countably infinite rank. Then there exists an epimorphism $\phi: F_\infty\to G$. There exists a Riemann surface $Y$ with the fundamental group $F_\infty$, namely, the complex plane ${\mathbb C}$ with a discrete  closed countably infinite subset removed (say, the subset of integers). We obtain an epimorphism $\phi: \pi_1(Y)\to G$. Let $N$ denote the kernel of $\phi$ and $p: X\to Y$ the (connected) covering space corresponding to the subgroup $N< \pi_1(Y)$. The group $G$ acts as the Galois group of the covering $p$. Lifting the complex structure from $Y$ to $X$ via $p$, makes $X$ a Riemann surface and the group $G$ acts effectively and biholomorphically on $X$. qed

Incidentally, Greenberg's proof starts similarly, except he would use a compact Riemann surface $Y$, hence, $X$ will be also compact since $G$ is finite. The hard part of his proof is to observe (by a dimension count for suitable Teichmuller spaces) that if $Y$ is chosen generically, then $X$ has no conformal automorphisms other than those coming from $G$.

Lastly, if one allows, say, connected, nontrivial Lie groups $G$ in this problem then only few groups $G$ appear as subgroups of conformal automorphism groups: $S^1$, $S^1\times S^1$, ${\mathbb R}$, ${\mathbb C}, {\mathbb C}^*$, $PSL(2, {\mathbb R}), PSL(2, {\mathbb C})$, $SO(3)$, and few more solvable groups: The group of affine automorphisms of the real line, the group of complex affine automorphisms of the complex plane ${\mathbb C}$, and its subgroup ${\mathbb C}\rtimes S^1$.